# Why the application crashes when I implements View.OnClickListener on the detail page of a list item?

Tags: android, onclick

I am using a list view when I click on each item it shows a detail page. In the detail page I want to have some buttons and also an action-bar for implementing the menu access but the app crashes when I use: implements View.OnClickListener this is the code, can you please tell me what is the problem ?.

This is my Class **AgendaDetail** :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
public class AgendaDetail extends ActionBarActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.agenda_detail);


    View btnClick = findViewById(R.id.emergencycall);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(AgendaDetail.this);
    View btnClick1 = findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    btnClick1.setOnClickListener(AgendaDetail.this);

    String selected_Device = getIntent().getStringExtra("device_name");

    // do whatever on this behalf of selected_Device String
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_menu) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.emergencycall) {

        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmergencyCall.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.cancel) {
        //define a new Intent for the second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Destination.class);
        //start the second Activity
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post your error log please

Comment: I am not able to see the error log ,  but as I remove the implements View.OnClickListener it works, the problem is with this line :( and without it I am not able to use buttons in the detail page !

Comment: Did you implement the `onClick(View)` function?

Comment: yes at the end of the code you can see it .

Comment: Anita mail, when you add line implements View.OnClickListener this line becime red? Simple move cursor on it and press add methods

Comment: add your imports to your question

Comment: Try casting View like  View btnClick = (View)findViewById(R.id.emergencycall);   and use View.onClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(AgendaDetail.this, EmergencyCall.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

instead

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmergencyCall.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
```